# How to turn off comment notifications for document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Using Google Script, I'm creating a document monthly in a shared directory by copying an existing document (method `File.makeCopy()`). The problem is I get email notifications every time someone leaves a comment in the newly created document even though notifications are disabled for the source document. How can I turn the notifications off for a copied document?

The code of the function that performs copying is below:

```
function createNewLogFile() {
  var rootDir = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B-gPh8Bs5aLhY2g2QXRFX2hycUU');
  var curDate = new Date();
  var curYear = curDate.getFullYear();
  var nextMonth = curDate.getMonth() + 2;
  nextMonth = (nextMonth < 10) ? '0' + nextMonth : (nextMonth > 12) ? '1' : nextMonth;

  var folderIter = rootDir.getFoldersByName((nextMonth > 12) ? curYear + 1 : curYear);
  var curYearFolder = folderIter.hasNext() ? folderIter.next() : rootDir.createFolder(curYear);
  var fileIter = curYearFolder.getFilesByName(nextMonth);

  if (!fileIter.hasNext()) {
    var gmLogTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1Vyd15DDiKqha9zlU_1Q8gRiqDY4Oqgl0VJ1uUYiBnCQ');
    var monthlyLogFile = gmLogTemplate.makeCopy(curYearFolder);
    monthlyLogFile.setName(nextMonth);
  }
}
```

Comment: For reviewers, this question has a irrelevant answer below(although upvoted). Do NOT close other questions as duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's already a [filed feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755104) which you can star or you may want to regularly check [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/) for any updates on this.

Currently, [Script Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/) still doesn't have method that supports this. Also, based from this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ygO5-eC8UB8), there's still no way to turn off notifications globally in Docs even in UI.

You may want to check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836765/manage-google-apps-script-execution-failure-notifications-for-triggers) and see if it will help you.

Comment: Irrelevant answer. OP is not asking about Trigger failure notifications.